# Exchange 2003 - e-mail updating but then disapearing

Tags: exchange-2003

We recently had some of the HDs fail on our server. these drives controlled the operating system Microsoft small business 2003, C: drive. the exchange is held on a separate set of drive, F: drive. these drives did not fail. We Replaced and restored the C: drive but not the F: drive.

Now the problem is that some not all of our user outlook accounts seem unable to "hold" new e-mail received from the exchange through our server.

the Exchange accounts are recognized as connected on the user's work station
they pull e-mail down on a send/receive command. but not automatically.

all new e-mail shows up when the user's station is syncing. it seems to sync all mail not just new mail. no duplicate entries are created for any e-mail. this takes about a half hour to an hour.

after the send and receive operation completes, generating no errors, all new mail received since the crash on our server is removed from the users account. "poof" no leftover, it's as if the new e-mail had never been received or identified.

We can then restart the send/receive request and the exact same thing happens.

New e-mail can be sent from these workstations and are received by the rest of the world.

Tried creating new mail profile in Windows 7, XP but problem persists even with fresh account creation.

any ideas?

Exchange 2003 server. Mix of 2003 and 2010 outlook.

Comment: Explain more about the failure. When you say Exchange server was held "inside" other drives, what you do mean? Are you saying you had SBS installed on the C: drive, for example, and your Exchange databases were simply stored on another drive or partition? Was Exchange physically installed on something other than C:?

Comment: editing above for clarity. C: drive held the operating system. then a Data drive F: held the actual exchange program / data. We only replaced and restored the C drive. C and F are physical drives not just partitions.

Comment: The program data would be useless, I assume you reinstalled Exchange as a part of SBS and recovered your databases?

Comment: no the exchange wasn't reinstalled it was there from the backup restore we did to the C drive. but the data and program was installed to the F drive. the C drive would only have held what ever the operating system needed to recognize the program installed on the F drive.

Comment: Exchange is so tightly integrated into SBS, that if the operating system completely failed, and you only reinstalled the OS, you have a lot of work to do getting Exchange going again. (possibly a call to Microsoft) You are likely in for a ton of headaches until you rebuild the entire SBS including Exchange and restore your mailboxes and other data.

Comment: Cool making the call then.